# What is wrong with this code of file handling in c?

Tags: c, file-handling, getchar, putchar, getc

I am trying to write content in a file from terminal. File is creating but content is not written into the file.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<math.h>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        FILE *fp;
        fp=fopen(argv[1],"w");
        char ch;
        while((ch=getchar())!=EOF)
        {
           putc(ch,fp);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Sidenote: Always check return values of I/O functions, including `fopen` and `putc`.

Comment: How do you signal EOF?

Comment: what happen if you display the character being read just before calling `putc()`?

Comment: Problem is not reproduce able. This code is working as expected for me.

Comment: `getchar()` returns a `int`, not a `char`, so `char ch;` -> `int ch;`.

Comment: You should check if `fopen(argv[1],"w")` returns `NULL`, that means the file could not be created for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't signal EOF (<kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> in Windows and <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> in Linux), then the loop will continue to execute until it receives that signal.

If you attempt to read the file with your own eyes while the program is still on execution, then the file stream will not have close (`fclose(fp);` will not have execute), thus the file will appear to you empty, even though the content will be shown to you, when the file stream closes.

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(argv[1],"w");
    char ch;
    while(1)
    {
        ch = (char)getchar();
        putc(ch,fp);
        if(ch == '.') break;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```